# Why are Mayavi inline plots showing up as text in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I followed the instructions located [here](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html#using-mayavi-in-jupyter-notebooks) for setting up inline plots with mayavi in jupyter notebook but it is not working. When I run the following code,

```
from mayavi import mlab

mlab.init_notebook()
mlab.test_plot3d()
```

instead of displaying the plot inline in the notebook it prints the following below the cell:

```
Image(value=b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01\x90
\x00\x00\x01^\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00$?\xde_\x00\…
```

Why might this be happening? I have made sure that mayavi is updated to version `4.7.1` and that I am using the `ipy` backend.

Comment: it works with me using [Canopy 3.5](https://assets.enthought.com/downloads/#civ-186) out of the box. Did you run `jupyter nbextension install --py mayavi --user` previous to running `jupyter notebook` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the backend from ipy to 'x3d' for interactive plots or to 'png' for static plots:

```
mlab.init_notebook(backend='x3d')
```

If you're working with JupyterLab you should launch the classic notebook and try it again.

Changeing to classic and using x3d instead of ipy solved it for me.

Comment: Tx for your answer. The classic  `http://localhost:8888/tree/` instead the lab `http://localhost:8888/lab/` works for me too. A QUESTION: Sometimes - I can not reproduce it - a mayavi windows appeard on the desktop (outside of Jupyter) which had controls to view the object from different angels. How can I call that ?